# Is there a way to convert a CA certificate to a QR code?

Tags: wireless-networking, certificate, wifi-configuration, qr-code

Is there a way to convert a CA certificate to a QR code so that it can be downloaded and installed with a phone? We want the QR code to install the certificate on the phone so that users can join the WiFi network. We host the link to the certificate on our intranet which cant be accessed without joining the wifi. Some providers don't let users join a network without a certificate so they can't join and get the certificate. As the current way is join with out authentication then get the certificate to authenticate the wifi.

Comment: That seems dodge. By CA cert did you mean cert allowing you to MITM their web traffic or were you referring to a cert used for WPA cert to access wifi (which I dont think is a CA type cert)?

Comment: If it’s a CA certificate then it should already be trusted by any browser or os on the market unless it’s a self-signed certificate

Comment: What is it you actually want to install on the phone? A client certificate which identifies the device to your auth system? Or a CA certificate for... what purpose? What is the error/symptonm you currently get on the phone? What kind of authentication does your WiFi network need?

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm assuming it's for Wi-Fi auth – very common to use internal CAs for WPA-Enterprise (PEAP) authentication, as in the past most phones didn't have the necessary features to allow using a public CA for that purpose. (Nowadays that's no longer an issue.)

Comment: You could get the CONTENT of the certificate, but it would require converting the text of the cert content into an actual cert file and then manually importing that into the system, which is a difficult work around. jcaron's answer seems the better way to do this: present the cert using a means devices already support (a web site and file) and serve the URL to that site/page as a QR code.

Answer (score 2):

While I doubt it's actually a CA certificate you need to install to fix problems joining a WiFi network, you can quite simply:

- Publish the certificate on any web server
- Get the relevant URL
- Create a QR Code with that URL

iPhones will then go through multiple steps and warnings before they let you install the certificate. Haven't checked what Android devices do.

There may be restrictions if the phone is managed through some kind of MDM (but in that case, you should use the MDM to push the certificate).

Note that if you have issues joining a WiFi network, it is more likely you need a client certificate (and associated private key) rather than a CA cert. In this case, you should make sure the private key is well protected. And of course the certificate and key should be specific to a single device.